# Why is $\mathbb{E}(d(\mu, X)^2) \leq \mathbb{E}|\mu - X|^2$, where $d$ is an intrinsic distance on a unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

The source materials is the paper [Intrinsic Means on the Circle: Uniqueness, Locus and Asymptotics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2141) by Hotz and Huckerman, pp. 4.

Namely, let $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n ~ X $ be i.i.d. r.v.s which are mappings from a probability space $(\Omega, A, \mathbb{P})$ to the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$, which represents the unit circle $S^1$. The intrinsic distance is defined for a point $\mu \in S^1$ and an outcome $X$ as $d(\mu, X) = \left| \mu - X - 2\pi\nu^{(X)}(\mu)\right|$, with $\nu^{(X)}(\mu) = \begin{cases}1 &: \mu > 0, X \in [-\pi, \mu - \pi)\\-1 &: \mu < 0, X \in (\pi + \mu, \pi)\\ 0 &: \text{else }\\
\end{cases}$.

Define the intrinsic variance as $V(\mu) = \mathbb{E}(d(\mu, X)^2)$ and let $\mu^*$ be the global minimizer of $V$.

Then the authors state that:

> Since $V(\mu) \leq \mathbb{E}\left|\mu - X\right|^2$ with equality for $\mu = 0$, the latter function being minimized by $\mu = \mathbb{E}X$, we see that $\mu^* = 0$ locally minimizing $V$ implies that $\mathbb{E}X = 0$.

What I honestly don't understand is that why does the inequality hold for all $\mu$ and $X$? Since what if $\mu < 0, X \in (\pi + \mu, \pi)$?

As a bonus question, is the following assessment about the rest of the statement valid: If $\mu^* = 0$, then $V(\mu) = \mathbb{E}(\left|X\right|)$, which is minimized by $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$. Hence because the variance is minimized by the expected value, $\mu = \mathbb{E}X$, it follows that if $\mu^* = 0$, then necessarily $\mathbb{E}X = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\mu-X|^2 - |\mu-X-2\pi\nu|^2 = 4\pi\nu(\mu-X-\pi\nu).$$
If $\nu(\mu) = -1,$ then $\mu < 0$ and $X>\pi+\mu$, so above is:
$$|\mu-X|^2 - |\mu-X-2\pi\nu|^2=-4\pi(\mu+\pi-X)>0.$$

If $\nu(\mu)=1$, then $\mu > 0$ and $X<\mu-\pi$ and so :
$$|\mu-X|^2 - |\mu-X-2\pi\nu|^2=4\pi(\mu-\pi-X)>0.$$